# Using 2 tables to report on a status SQL Query

Tags: sql, count, left-join, case

I'm writing a report that brings back Landstatus's for our new clients. 
We have 3 options (Gold, Silver and Bronze and null if the user doesn't add there status).
The data gets stored in 2 different tables `dbo.tbl_Profile_ProjectLand` and `dbo.Tasks`

At times i find that `dbo.tbl_Profile_ProjectLand` has a diffrent landstatus than `dbo.Tasks`

For my report i want to use the `dbo.tbl_Profile_ProjectLand` as my main table and if that doesn't have a result for landstatus then use the landstatus in the `dbo.Tasks`

The problem is that i cant seem to get the query right. 
here is my code.

```
SELECT 
Count
            ((CASE WHEN pp.landstatus > 0 THEN pp.landstatus
            ELSE t.landstatus END)) As Taken,
                ls.Description
FROM         dbo.Tasks AS t 
    LEFT JOIN
             tbl_User AS u 
    ON t.TakenBy = u.UserId 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_Profile_ProjectLand AS pp
ON t.Fk_ProfileID = pp.Fk_ProfileID
    LEFT JOIN
             tbl_DDLandStatus AS ls 
    ON t.LandStatus = ls.Id
    LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.tbl_EnquiryType AS e
    ON t.EnquiryType = e.EnquirytypeId
where
(Month(t.DueDate) = Month(getdate()) 
AND YEAR(t.DueDate) = YEAR(getdate ()))and t.EnquiryType = 1  
GROUP BY 
ls.Description 
ORDER BY ( CASE ls.Description
              WHEN 'Gold - owned' THEN 1
              WHEN 'Silver - identified / offered' THEN 2
              WHEN 'Bronze - no land' THEN 3
              ELSE 0
            END)
```

This brings back the following results

```
Taken   Description
40      NULL
34      Gold - owned
28      Silver - identified / offered
8       Bronze - no land
```

Now i have checked the 40 null result and this is not correct as there is Null value in the
 `dbo.tbl_Profile_ProjectLand` table and a 6 in the `dbo.Tasks` that represents a Bronze status.

I hope i have explained this OK as iv almost confused myself here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

I have found a way to do this however i cant seem to group them. here is my new code

```
SELECT 
COUNT ((CASE WHEN pp.landstatus > 0 THEN pp.landstatus
            ELSE t.landstatus END)) As Taken,
((CASE WHEN ls.Description > '' THEN ls.Description
            ELSE lst.description END)) As 'Description'
FROM dbo.Tasks AS t 
LEFT JOIN tbl_DDLandStatus AS lst
    ON t.landstatus = lst.Id 
LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_Profile_ProjectLand AS pp
    ON t.Fk_ProfileID = pp.Fk_ProfileID
LEFT JOIN tbl_DDLandStatus AS ls 
    ON pp.LandStatus = ls.Id
WHERE (Month(t.DueDate) = Month(getdate()) 
AND YEAR(t.DueDate) = YEAR(getdate ()))and t.EnquiryType = 1  
GROUP BY 
ls.Description,lst.description
ORDER BY ( CASE ls.Description
              WHEN 'Gold - owned' THEN 1
              WHEN 'Silver - identified / offered' THEN 2
              WHEN 'Bronze - no land' THEN 3
              ELSE 0
            END)
```

This brings back this result which is spot on but doesn't group.

```
Taken   Description
22      NULL
7       Bronze - no land
22      Gold - owned
14      Silver - identified / offered
5       Gold - owned
13      Gold - owned
7       Gold - owned
16      Silver - identified / offered
1       Silver - identified / offered
1       Silver - identified / offered
11      Silver - identified / offered
```

Any idea how i can get them grouped by description?

Comment: What is the count of null actually in both the tables...

Comment: What values does landstatus  column hold ..

Comment: Hey Rusty can u respond...

Comment: Hi Azar the count on null is should be 28. LandStatus holds 6 = bronze 7 = silver and 8 = gold

Comment: So in table  tbl_Profile_ProjectLand the land status is NULL but in the Task table it is set to 6 which should put it in the bronze status

Comment: change "GROUP BY 
ls.Description,lst.description"

Comment: to "GROUP BY (CASE WHEN ls.Description > '' THEN ls.Description
            ELSE lst.description END)"

Comment: I would also suggest you try a new column which is simply "count(*)" in that latest query. Does it produce the same numbers as "Taken"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the nature of the joins to accommodate the difference in status values is correct.

I think you will also find that you don't need the case expression in the COUNT()

All you need to do is tweak you most recent query in the group by to use the same case expression you use for the description column.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(*) as Taken
    , ((CASE
            WHEN ls.Description > ''
                  THEN ls.Description
            ELSE lst.description
      END)) AS 'Description'
FROM dbo.Tasks AS t
      LEFT JOIN tbl_DDLandStatus AS lst             ON t.landstatus = lst.Id
      LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_Profile_ProjectLand AS pp   ON t.Fk_ProfileID = pp.Fk_ProfileID
      LEFT JOIN tbl_DDLandStatus AS ls              ON pp.LandStatus = ls.Id
WHERE (MONTH(t.DueDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
      AND YEAR(t.DueDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
      AND t.EnquiryType = 1
GROUP BY
      (CASE
            WHEN ls.Description > ''
                  THEN ls.Description
            ELSE lst.description
      END)
ORDER BY
      (CASE ls.Description
            WHEN 'Gold - owned'
                  THEN 1
            WHEN 'Silver - identified / offered'
                  THEN 2
            WHEN 'Bronze - no land'
                  THEN 3
            ELSE 0
      END)
```

### ---

---

Below: previous attempt (fail):
Not quite sure of these:

- there are 2 tables not referenced (required for the count?)
- the case    expression is the equivalent of count(*), I think you
  need to NOT    include the else, OR do "else NULL".

Try this:

```
SELECT
      COUNT
      (CASE
            WHEN pp.landstatus > 0
                  THEN pp.landstatus
      END)                             AS Taken
    , COALESCE(ls.Description, 'NULL') AS Description
FROM dbo.Tasks AS t
  LEFT JOIN tbl_User AS u                      ON t.TakenBy = u.UserId
  LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_Profile_ProjectLand AS pp  ON t.Fk_ProfileID = pp.Fk_ProfileID
  LEFT JOIN tbl_DDLandStatus AS ls             ON t.LandStatus = ls.Id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_EnquiryType AS e           ON t.EnquiryType = e.EnquirytypeId
WHERE (MONTH(t.DueDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
      AND YEAR(t.DueDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
      AND t.EnquiryType = 1
GROUP BY
      COALESCE(ls.Description, 'NULL')
ORDER BY
      (CASE ls.Description
            WHEN 'Gold - owned'
                  THEN 1
            WHEN 'Silver - identified / offered'
                  THEN 2
            WHEN 'Bronze - no land'
                  THEN 3
            ELSE 0
      END)
```

Comment: Hi User2067753 this doesn't bring back the information i require it appears to  be bringing back very low fixure im expecting almost 3 x the amount to come back.

Comment: I have revised it by returning the joined tables to you originals, presumably you needed/wanted all those tables for the count.

Comment: user2067753 It's bringing back the same as the last query mate.

Comment: What i want to do i use these 2 table to bring back landstatus SELECT landstatus FROM tasks
WHERE (Month(DueDate) = Month(getdate()) 
AND YEAR(DueDate) = YEAR(getdate ()))  using the FK_profileId as a join and if there is no value in the 


SELECT landstatus
 FROM tbl_Profile_ProjectLand
WHERE (Month(DateCreated) = Month(getdate()) 
AND YEAR(DateCreated) = YEAR(getdate ())) matching the 2 tables on FK_ProfileId and if tbl_Profile_ProjectLand table doesnt have a value for the landstatus then use the value of land status in table tasks

Comment: count( whatever ) will literally add 1 to the count as long as 'whatever' is not null

Comment: so, in your question, the case expression is the 'whatever', and it appears to me that it never gets a NULL so that count is exactly the same as count(*)

Comment: Thank you so much guys for you help on this it totally confused me. Thanks User2067753 for explaining and answring my question.

Answer (score 1):

Can u modify the case like this and check

```
Select count(case when pp.landstatus is not null then pp.landstatus 
              ELSE t.landstatus END) as taken , your query
```

Comment: This does not work it gives the same value as SELECT
Count
   ((CASE WHEN pp.landstatus > 0 THEN pp.landstatus
   ELSE t.landstatus END)) As Taken,

Comment: The exact same results Azar

Comment: It appears that its only bring back results for the 'Tasks' table and not the 'tbl_Profile_ProjectLand'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56705/discussion-between-azar-and-rustyhamster).